# I am getting an error when i run my node.js app ( also using rabbit )

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq, node-amqp

```
Error: Cannot find module 'amqplib/callback_api'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hello\Downloads\Private-Chat-App-Socket.io- 
master\Private-Chat-App-Socket.io-master\app.js:3:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
```

I have tried to solve the error by installing amqp using npm but it does not work and i have also searched for solutions on the internet but no luck.

[Pic of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV0Js.png)

Comment: try to run write the command 'make' in the terminal inside of your project and see if it helps

Comment: Nope doesn't help :(

Comment: have you tried the answer too?

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of your source code, it makes your question harder to read and/or answer. Consider writing a [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed you're declaring `amqp` twice. In line 3 and 6:

```
var amqp = require('amqplip/callback_api'),
```

So I will suggest you check your code and choose the one you'll wanna use.

That aside, I think what you're trying to use is [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) and not [amqp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp)

To resolve your problem, I will suggest you delete the `node_modules` dir completely, then run `npm install`, after which you run these:

```
npm install --save amqplib
```

This should solve your problem.